# Example of linear first order differential equation, with non unique solution.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm was stubling on the question of uniqueness of differential equations. I have a differential equation of the form $ \frac{d}{dt}y(t)= f(t)y(t), y(t_0)=p_0$ ie. a linear, first order differential equation and it seems to be the case, that one of the ways to determine uniqueness of the solutionfunction is to require continuity on a open interval of f(t). I couldn't find example which were not unique, could only find some where the diff. eq. was nonlinear. My question, does such exist and can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition of unicity and existence of a first order ODE $y'=g(t,y)$ is that $g(t,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$ (it is the statement of the [Picard-Lindelof theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)).

By the definition of Lipschitz continuity, $f(t) y(t)$ is Lipschitz continuous if $\exists K$ such that $\forall y$
$$
|f y_1 - f y_2| \leq K |y_1 - y_2|
$$
which is obviously satisfied if $K \geq f$ (see that $K$ is constant in relation to $y$).

Therefore, any ODE in the form $y'=f(t)y(t)$ has a unique solution.

Comment: I actually found a counter example $ \frac{dy(x)}{d x} = \frac{2}{(x-1)}y(x), y(0)=1$. There a for example these two solutions: $y(x)=(x-1)^2$ and $ y(x)=1_{x<1}(x-1)^2$

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand the second solution. What is $1_{x<1}$?

Comment: It is a not well made indicator, that is 1 for x<1, and 0 else. I meant $ 1_{(x<1)}$ but cant correct it anymore

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I can't help more then this, since I'm not a mathematician. But, in that case, there would not be an indetermination in $x=1$?

Comment: You could make f(1)=0 and the result is still true. Meaning that the differential equation is $\frac{d}{dx}y(x)=\frac{2}{x-1}y(x)1_{(x\neq1)}, y(0)=1$

Answer (score 1):

By the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), the solution to your problem is always  unique.